# automatic lock screen issue

Tags: lock

My Ubuntu 13.04 does automatic lock screen after X minutes, but the screen is still showing any opened windows. Only after we tried to click or type anything, Ubuntu will prompt password to unlock.

How we completely hide any windows open once the auto lock working.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/958353), there also is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/958353/comments/18) for this.